# How to set PHP memory_limit in DDEV

Tags: php, docker, shopware, ddev, shopware6

I am running a local shopware6 environment insider docker with DDEV configuration.

After trying to fetch all products (~11.000) via `https://sw6.ddev.site/api/search/product` I get following error:

`Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88686592 bytes)`

And it points me to:
`"file": "/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php", "line": 381`

which content is:

```
    /**
     * Sends content for the current web response.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sendContent()
    {
        echo $this->content;

        return $this;
    }
```

I know from our staging server how to adjust the memory limit and solve the problem, but in my local environment I set `memory_limit = 1024M`. SSHing to my container and executing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` the output is like `memory_limit => -1 => -1`

Now there are to possibilities:
Because of the uncapped memory limit the server can not (idk why) proceed my request

Any `DDEV, .env or .htaccess` configuration are overwriting the my modified php.ini file.

Path to my edited php.ini file:
`/var/www/html/config/etc/php7/conf.d/php.ini`

Content of php.ini:

```
[Date] 
date.timezone="UTC" 
 
memory_limit = 1024M 
upload_max_filesize = 6M 
max_execution_time = 30
```

Comment: I would try to first resolve _why_ it's using so much memory. Maybe you should bach your requests?

Comment: On my live and dev server there aren't not errors like this. So I think it should be fine
And I got MBP intel i9 32gb RAM, docker got 8gb RAM

Comment: The more products you have, the more RAM it will require. Extending memory limit will only solve your issue temporary

Comment: You are totally right. For the next days its fine to keep development going but for the future I have to investigate more further!

Comment: The issue here isn't how much is allocated to Docker; you're running out of `memory_limit`

Comment: Yes, but I realated this issue to docker because php.ini file after sshing to my container changes its content always back to its default value of "-1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help with the fact that your app is eating too much memory, and the default 1GB that DDEV sets up is far more than most production sites will allow. But if you want to change the 1GB limit, you'll do it with a config file in `.ddev/php/<name>.ini`, create the directory `.ddev/php` and add an ini file to it. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#custom-php-configuration-phpini

For example, a `.ddev/php/memlimit.ini` might have the contents:

```
[PHP]
memory_limit = 2G
```

But you'll need to figure out why your app is using so much memory to actually solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick. For me its unclear why I was not able to fetch all product records in my local environment, because its mirrored to the DEV and LIVE system

Comment: note to others finding this: if you cannot find .ddev/php/memlimit.ini you can just create it

Comment: Yes @DanielLefebvre, you have to create the directory and the file. So `mkdir -p .ddev/php` and then put your config into the .ini file in .ddev/php.

Comment: From the docs linked above: "You can provide additional PHP configuration for a project by creating a directory called .ddev/php/ and adding any number of *.ini PHP configuration files."